# jQuery Datatables Ajax Processing

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, datatables

I am using server side processing with jquery datatables mixed with MVC. I have a C# class to generate the columns and rows thats returning JSON. I can get it to work if I put it in an ajax success call without the server side processing but not sure how to do it with the processing in it. I think I need some sort of callback but not really sure. I can see the response back and all my data just can't figure out how to bind it. This is all happening on page load.

**DOES NOT WORK**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "StateFarmEInvoice/Adjuster/AjaxHandler",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "aoColumns": "not sure what to put here",
        "aaData": "not sure what to put here"
    });
});
```

**WORKS**

```
var ajax = ajaxReturn("Default.aspx/CreateJsDataTable", valJson);
    ajax.success(function (json) {
        var adminTable = $('.adminTable').dataTable({
            "bDestroy": true,
            "aoColumns": json.d.aoColumns,
            "aaData": json.d.aaData,
            "aaSorting": [[1, 'desc']],
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 25,
            "bAutoWidth": true
        });                       
        $('.massChange').show();
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried starting from the example on the [JQuery DataTables page](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)?  Are you sure you even need server-side processing?  It's likely you only want the data to come from the server, not that you want it processed there as well (such as sorting, filtering, etc).

Comment: Well I was using the server side processing because I am dealing with large data sets (~100k) so I wanted to chunk the data up. Making one call on the server then binding was slow.